# Long-ish term trailer rentals?

Tags: luggage-storage, long-term

We're moving out of a flat in Paris next month and moving into another flat elsewhere in France at some indeterminate point between July and September after we travel for a while.

Is there a way to avoid moving twice by renting a sealed trailer for an extended period, maybe leaving it with family elsewhere in France for a couple months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like [Mobilbox](http://www.mobilbox.fr/). They will drive a large (8m<sup>3</sup>) storage box to your home, you load your things into it, and then [they store it until you're ready](http://www.mobilbox.fr/stockage.html) and then they will bring the box to your destination and you unload it again. For an additional fee they will also [load and unload for you](http://www.mobilbox.fr/services-en-plus.html).